# My code always gets error 400 when using openweathermap api using geolocation. How can I solve this?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

[image]

I am trying to use openweathermap.org api by geolocation but I am having an error of 400 all the time and when I go to the browser and test the link with latitude, longitude, and api key, it shows this error:

[image]

Comment: The message is telling everything, latitude or longitude which value is start with 122.0311 is not exist or probably not as proper type(float).

Comment: The latitude and longitude were fetched using a flutter package called geolocation. Also the longitude and latitude has a data type of double.

Comment: Double uses for float in dart but can you try the link as manually(in browser) with the values you got?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd image is the result of manually putting it on the browser, with the lat and lon generated from the geolocation package

Comment: check my answer, you get the error because that number is out of range. If you use emulator try a new one or on a real device.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the number in error code and if I try it in latitude I get the same error, because it is out of range, latitudes range from -90 to 90 and longitudes range from -180 to 180. You can check your data is in range or not for each (you already printing them in your function as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem when you first call the function ... but if you called the function a second time it works. I solved this way hopefully work for you too.

```
http.Response response = await http.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${latitude.toString()}&lon=${longtude.toString()}&appid='+owm_apiKey);
    response = await http.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${latitude.toString()}&lon=${longtude.toString()}&appid='+owm_apiKey);
    if (response.statusCode == 200 ) {
```